# How do these factors affect engagement rings as an investment?

Tags: investing, jewelry

I'm shopping around for an engagement ring.  At the moment, I'm considering two options.  From a "will she like it?" perspective consider them equal.  (I say that because that is really the MOST important criteria)

I've found two options I really like, but they are dramatically different. One where the stone is 83% of the cost, with a relatively simple band.  The other option is that the stone is 63% of the cost with a more elaborate band with 10 small stones.

All else being equal, which one is a better investment?

Comment: investment? are you planning on selling the ring at some point in the future?

Comment: The simple answer is that the value of the ring will depend on what stylistic preferences are like at the time she is forced to sell it, plus all the randomness in value of the materials. My _personal_ bet would be that the simpler ring is more likely to retain value, but gods only know.  (This is one reason the traditional wedding ring is a plain gold band -- it can be assayed simply as its metal content.) However, I agree with @mhoran_psprep -- unless you expect to split up, investment value is the _least_ of your concerns.

Comment: Hah, I didn't mean to sound like I *planned* to sell it.  (Nor do I have a choice since its a gift)  However, I would prefer giving a ring that is as liquid as possible.  Maybe that isn't romantic to you, but I plan on giving the best gift possible.  In all regards.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As an investment, count the gold value and discount the stone to (not by) 30% of the price you're paying for it.

Diamond jewelry is consumption goods, not an investment - the market is not liquid, you're likely paying 100-200% markup over the wholesale price, and you'll be likely to sell it only below the wholesale price, so you lose a majority of its value the moment you walk out of the shop.